# How can I play a flashmovie which is in my references? (C#)

Tags: c#, flash, object, reference

My program works, except I want to take a flash movie out of the references, not from an external location. The FlashObject.Movie requires a string location though, and I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas? This should be possible I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract you flash from reference to temp folder, and play from there. Or, alternatively, you can use one of the commercial libraries with streams support (For example: [f-in-box](http://f-in-box.com/))